# MySQL NOT IN Select

Tags: mysql

I have a following table in my project

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id | old_id | op_status | tr_status |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |        | issue     | Approved  |
|  2 |        | issue     | Approved  |
|  3 |        | issue     | Approved  |
|  4 |      1 | issue     | Issued    |
|  5 |      3 | issue     | Issued    |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to select records WHERE tr_status='Approved' and NOT IN id in the old_row_id. In this example no need to select id(s) 1 and 3 that are in old_row_id as the following result.

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id | old_id | op_status | tr_status |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
|  2 |        | issue     | Approved  |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I used the following query.

`SELECT id, old_row_id, op_status, tr_status FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (old_row_id)`.

But outs the following result.

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id | old_id | op_status | tr_status |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |        | issue     | Approved  |
|  2 |        | issue     | Approved  |
|  3 |        | issue     | Approved  |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

What may be wrong with me ? can anyone help me ?

Comment: See about joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
SELECT id, old_id, op_status, tr_status 
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT old_id FROM table)
AND tr_status = 'Approved'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase your query using exists logic:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.old_id, t1.op_status, t1.tr_status
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    t1.tr_status = 'Approved' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.old_id = t1.id);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You will want to left join the table to itself on the old ID, then eliminate the records where there is a match.

For example:

```
SELECT A.id, A.old_row_id, A.op_status, A.tr_status 
FROM table A
LEFT JOIN table B ON A.id = B.old_row_id
WHERE B.id IS NULL
AND A.tr_status = 'Approved';
```

Answer (score -1):

In they way you've tried to solve it, you're matching the old_id with the value of the row itself. You must derivate the table to create a cartesian product:

```
SELECT id, old_id, op_status, tr_status 
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT IFNULL(old_id, 0) FROM table)
AND tr_status = 'Approved'
```

Also IFNULL to also include those record in the subquery, otherwise can't be compared with null

Comment: No idea who downvotes this answer, but the accepted answer so far does not work if `old_id` contains `NULL` since `NULL` does not matches with `NULL`